# Replace string in linux bash

Tags: bash, sed

I am writing a bash script for installing django with postgresql database automatically.
Now , I want to replace database name by command ,since it is using sqlite3 database file path.

I wrote this command:

```
sudo sed -i 's/os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),/'$project_name',/g' $projects_name/settings.py
```

But this is not changed while I am making the django project.

How to change this , please help me.

Comment: `$project_name` and `$projects_name` are different variables?

Comment: sorry, `$projects_name` will `$project_name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double-quotes around `sed` for variable expansion & to preserve single quotes.

```
sed -i "s/os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),/$project_name,/g" "$project_name/settings.py"
```

tested working fine on `GNU sed version 4.2.1`

Comment: Thanks, it is working.

Comment: @Engr.TanbirHasan: Happy to help!

Comment: It works as double quotes around the sed command preserve single quotes in `'db.sqlite3'`. But please note that variable expansion is not the issue here.

Comment: @Kenavoz: totally agree to it! Added a note for the same.

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the quotes in `'db.sqlite3'`:

```
sudo sed -i 's/os\.path\.join(BASE_DIR, '\''db\.sqlite3'\''),/'$project_name',/g' $projects_name/settings.py
```

Your sed pattern is `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, db.sqlite3),` because quotes in `'db.sqlite3'` are not interpreted as literal `'`. Instead they close and reopen the sed command.